# cannot reference multiple projects in linux with dotnet

Tags: .net, build, .net-core, centos

I am using dotnet core 2.0 on a centos machine and encountered an odd problem when trying to reference two projects.

My main project is a console application. It references two other projects (class libraries). 
When compiling on a windows machine there is no problem, but when compiling on a centos machine, DOTNET BUILD just freezes.

I made a simple example here:
https://github.com/dansha/fms

any ideas?

Comment: What version of CentOS are you running?

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)